# The nuances of working with deep links in Compose Android

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, android-deep-link

Good day! I’m trying to understand the nuances of Deep Links’ work and some questions arose that I couldn’t find the answers to on my own. The questions are:

1. Is it possible to implement a navigation chain when a user navigates through a deep link? More precisely, there are, say, 2 screens:

   composable(
   route = "user_data",
   deeplinks = {
   uriParretn = ... some url { some-param }
   }
   ...

   composable(
   route = "user_details_data",
   deeplinks = {
   uriParretn = ... some url { some-param }
   }

I need that when the user gets to the “user_data” screen and, for example, clicks on the “Back” button, he gets, for example, to “user_details”. How can this be achieved? P.S. We have implemented a solution through a custom handleAppLink, in which we specify navigation, but we are interested in the “out of the box” option.

2. How does the "deeplinks" option in composable navigation work in a KMM (KMP) application? How will it behave on iOS?
3. How does the deep link behave in case of errors? For example, the user's device has lost its Internet connection and he sees a basic error screen, but when the network appears, he can re-access this deep link. Where will this deep link be saved in case of an error?

It was to these questions that we could not find detailed answers/articles/materials. If you can share information about this, I would be grateful. Thank you in advance!